# Examples of Commutative Rings with $1$ that are not integral domains besides $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm doing a problem where I'm trying to find a counterexample to some statement about commutative rings with $1$ when the ring is not a domain. I've tried looking at $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, for composite $n$, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample yet (maybe the statement is also true for nondomains, but I don't see any reason why that would be the case), so I was wondering: what are some other examples of unital commutative rings that are not domains?

Comment: $$\Bbb Z_n:=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$$ , for any **non-prime** $\;n\;$ .\

Comment: Polynomial rings over nondomains?

Comment: I meant nondomains besides $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Nishant - Look, several respondents have given you nice examples of rings with 1 that are not integral domains, ywt none of them seems to satisfy you. So, I would ask what is the statement about this type of ring that you are trying to disprove, and why, exactly, are the examples provided not good enough.

Comment: All right. The problem is as follows: if two elements of $R$ generate the same ideal, then one is a unit multiple of the other. I don't immediately see why this would be true for non-domains, but I haven't been able to find counterexamples in any of the non-domains given.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can figure out how to prove that...

Comment: After some consideration I must apologise; my previous comment was wrong. For any integral domain $R$, the ring $R[x,y,z]/(x-xyz)$ yields a counterexample.

Comment: Are the units of that ring just the units of $R$?

Comment: If you would like to see a counterexample, perhaps you could ask another question (in stead of posing it in the comments).

Comment: It's fine, I was able to answer my own question. :)

Answer (score 9):

For a very generic example: ${\mathbb Z}[X,Y]/(XY)$. This is in a certain sense the simplest non-domain in that you can build an obvious map from this ring to every (unital commutative) ring that is not a domain.

**Edit.** This may go way too far, but let me formalize the informal claim above that this is the simplest non-domain.

Consider the category ${\cal C}$ of (unital commutative) rings with two chosen elements, i.e., objects are triples $(R,r,s)$ with $R$ a ring and $r, s \in R$; morphisms are ring homomorphism preserving the two elements. The object $({\mathbb Z}[X,Y],X,Y)$ is the initial object of ${\cal C}$.

Now look at the full subcategory ${\cal D}$ of ${\cal C}$ on the objects $(R,r,s)$ where $R$ is a non-domain and $r, s \in R$ are non-zero elements such that $rs = 0$. The object $({\mathbb Z}[X,Y]/(XY),X,Y)$ is the initial object of ${\cal D}$. So in this sense $({\mathbb Z}[X,Y]/(XY)$ is the smallest non-domain.

**Edit.** And an example adressing the question by the OP in the comments ("In a non-domain $R$, if $(r) = (s)$ is then $r = us$ for some unit $u$?") constructed in a similar fassion.

Look at the ideal $I = (X - UY, Y - VX)$ of ${\mathbb Z}[X,Y,U,V]$ and consider the ring $R = {\mathbb Z}[X,Y,U,V]/I$. In this ring $(X) = (Y)$, since $Y = VX \in (X)$ and $X = UY \in (Y)$. And $U$ is not a unit, since $R/(U) \cong {\mathbb Z}[X,Y,U,V]/(X - UY, Y - VX, U) \cong {\mathbb Z}[V]$ which is not the trivial ring.

Answer (score 6):

Given a set $S$, the power set of $S$ with addition given by symmetric difference and multiplication given by intersection, is a commutative ring with unity, but as long as $S$ has $2$ or more elements, $ \mathcal P \left({S}\right)$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: Ooh, that's a good one! Unfortunately, I don't think it helps me with my problem...

Comment: What is your problem? Knowing that would make it easier to find a good ring.

Comment: Is the following statement true for a nondomain: if $r$ and $s$ generate the same principal ideal, then $r=us$, for some unit $u\in R$.

Comment: Maybe try $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$? I haven't worked through the details but I am pretty sure $((2,2)) = ((2,4))$, even though one isn't a unit multiple of the other.

Comment: Nope, they differ by $(1, -1)$, which is a unit.

Comment: You are right. I feel like I should have seen that immediately (or at least wondered why no one else had suggested this if it worked).

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked for rings besides $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. I also realized that direct products of rings of that form, and more generally rings of functions into those rings wouldn't work either, since you just find a unit at each point and construct the unit of the direct product by concatenating them.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever $R$ and $S$ are two nontrivial commutative rings with $1$, the product ring $R\times S$ has an identity, namely $(1,1)$, and is commutative; on the other hand, all elements of the form $(r,0)$ and $(0,s)$ are zero-divisors, so that $R\times S$ is not a domain. (Do you know what I mean by $R\times S$?) This is related to the $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ example; by the [Chinese remainder theorem for rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings), every ring of the form $\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes, for example, is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ and is therefore not a domain.
Similarly, the product of any number of commutative rings with $1$ is not a domain.

Here's a less algebraic example: the ring of continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is commutative and has an identity -- the constant function $1$ -- but has many zero divisors.